# Bash script, cannote replace string in a file with escaped $ and &

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sed

I have creatd  a shell script which takes a string as input. If the string contains '$' or '&', then I need to raplace those characters with '\$' and '\&'. I could done that with sed command. After this I want to replace a word in a particular text file with that corresponding string.

Please see this section for more clarification.

This is my file.

```
test.txt

hello my root password is root.
```

Now, I want to change the word root with a string. The string can be anything which may include special characters like $ or &.

If I want to replace root with the string `my&rootpa$$`, then it should looks like `my\&rootpa\$\$` in text file.

This is my shell scipt

```
#!/bin/bash
dothis(){
    rootpass=$(echo "$1" | sed -r 's/\$/\\$/g');
    rootpass=$(echo "$rootpass" | sed -r 's/\&/\\&/g');
    echo $rootpass;
    sed -i "s/root/$rootpass/g" test.txt
}
dothis "my&rootpa$$";
```

This script works properly upto `echo $rootpass`, which means when I echo the string it will display my\&rootpa\$\$.
But in the file it looks my&rootpa$$ instead of my\&rootpa\$\$. Whats wrong with the script.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape `$` and `&` multiple times, because when using the `sed -i` command they need to be escaped as well. If not escaped multiple times they will be interpreted as single `&` and `$` signs.

```
#!/bin/bash
dothis(){
    rootpass=$(echo "$1" | sed -r 's/\$/\\\\\\\$/g');
    rootpass=$(echo "$rootpass" | sed -r 's/\&/\\\\\\\&/g');
    echo $rootpass;
    sed -i "s/root/$rootpass/g" test.txt
}
dothis 'my&rootpa$$';
```

This worked for me. The output is:

```
my\\\&rootpa\\\$\\\$
```

And test looks like this after execution:

```
user@host:~# cat test.txt
hello my my\&rootpa\$\$ password is my\&rootpa\$\$.
```